# Firefox Blob removes mime type from files

Tags: javascript, firefox

This used to work in Firefox prior to Firefox Quantum(v 57). The code still works in Chrome but not in Firefox anymore.

User selects an image from his local computer, then creates a `Blob` with some JSON information and the file, like this:

```
var fileElement = $("<input>").attr({
        "type": "file",
        "accept": "image/*"
    }).hide()
    .on("change", function () {
        var fileList = this.files;

        if (fileList.length > 0) {
            var file = fileList[0];
                    var str = JSON.stringify({
                        "uid": info.uid,
                        "utype": info.utype
                    });

                        var blob = new Blob([str.length, str, file]);
                        WebSocketConnection.sendMessage(blob);   

        }

    });
```

Then on the server side I extract the JSON string and get the information I want, then extract the mime type from the file and based on that mime type I save the file on server disk with one of this extensions `[".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif"]`.

Since Firefox quantum this is not working and the received mime type is `application/octet-stream`

Is this a Firefox bug or did something changed in the api and I need to add some changes to my code?

Comment: Wait what are `info` and `file` and which MIME are you talking about? You know that you can (and should) use a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) to send multipart data (e.g binary data along with JSON data)? If `file` is a binary file as I'm afraid it is, you are building a weird text file, and I'm really surprised you never encountered any problem before now.

Comment: @Kaiido info is an  object {uid:"unique id",utype:"user_type"}, some basic information about user id and type., file is the selected file from local computer using a <input type="file"> element

Comment: @Kaiido true,but I need to send the file using websockets, and like I said is working on Chrome and used to work on Firefox

Comment: That what I was afraid of... So you do understand you are converting your binary file to an UTF8 text file? Once again, I'm really suprised it did ever work. The correct way is `var fD = new FormData(); fD.append('your_file_field', file); fD.append('info', JSON.stringify(info));` or even `fD.append('uid, info.uid); ...` if you want to be verbose.

Comment: Through ws? I'm no specialist there, but I'm sure your way is the incorrect one. Ps: you should specify it in your question (tags?) if it blocks you from using FormData and to answer your question, I'm not convinced it can be considered an FF bug since binary data is supposed to be escaped in JSON.

Comment: @Kaiido I've updated the main code to better understand what I was trying to achieve. The problem is in that line var blob = new Blob([str.length, str, file]); file will have his mime type removed ( or replaced) when the blob is created. (Firefox 57&58 only)  See my answer to this question and how I managed to make it work. Unfortunately I need to send the file via websocket in this case and I have no access to HTTP server to send the data through FormData

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166632/discussion-between-doua-beri-and-kaiido).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work.  I still think this is a bug since it used to work in Firefox older versions.

In the end I converted selected file to `ArrayBuffer` then created the Blob file with  that `ArrayBuffer`. I also updated the main question code to better understand what's happening.

```
var fileElement = $("<input>").attr({
        "type": "file",
        "accept": "image/*"
    }).hide()
    .on("change", function () {
        var fileList = this.files;

        if (fileList.length > 0) {
            var file = fileList[0];
                    var str = JSON.stringify({
                        "uid": info.uid,
                        "utype": info.utype
                    });

                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function () {
                        var arrayBuffer = this.result;
                        var blob = new Blob([str.length, str, arrayBuffer]);
                        WebSocketConnection.sendMessage(blob);                            
                    }
                    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

        }

    });
```

Comment: And now you are reading the hole file into memory, how dose 800mb files work for you?

Comment: @Endless I limit files to 4MB but I cut that from code to keep it simple